Is usury a form of extortion?
Is usury a form of extortion?
St. Paul lists extortion among the mortal sins in 1 Cor. 6:10: "…nor extortioners (άρπαγες, rapaces, "the rapacious"), shall possess the kingdom of God."
Ex. 22:25 relates extortion and usury: "If thou lend money to any of my people that is poor, that dwelleth with thee, thou shalt not be hard upon them as an extortioner [exactor], nor oppress them with usuries."

In Israel, where the shekel was intimately bound to weights and measures, there was no inflation. If currencies fluctuate then this introduces a complication. It could be argued that interest (usury) is necessary to re-align the value of an investment. Generally speaking, among a family, usury would be repugnant. But in business with strangers, then can it be called a 'sin' for someone to make a living by 'trading' money itself. If it is wrong to make a profit then society would collapse for we need an economy to structure a nation.

@NigelJ There are morally just ways of making a profit; not all profit-making is usurious.

Yes, one can add to the price of a commodity to cover not only the cost of transportation but also the cost of one's own wages, in order to make some money to support oneself and one's dependants - in other words, a 'profit'. And if that is all, then it is not iniquitous. But it becomes extortionate if one raises, say, the price of wheat beyond the ability of the common populace to afford to feed their families. Likewise with lending money to people so that they can purchase a home. Is it wrong to make a profit on lending that money ?

@NigelJ interest and usury are not synonymous. Not all interest is usurious.

@eques Such as . . . . . . .  ?

@NigelJ such as what? You mean what form of interest is not usury?

@NigelJ "But in business with strangers, then can it be called a 'sin' for someone to make a living by 'trading' money itself.  ... we need an economy to structure a nation"  Would you think the whole capital market where stocks, bonds, mortgages, etc. are being traded and used for raising capital for a government or a company (and where interest is a fundamental feature) is a necessary evil, or are there Godly principles that a government or a capital market system should adhere?

As long as there is inflation or income tax, interest (or equivalent charges) will be necessary.
E.g. If I lend you $100 for a year and charge 3⅓% interest, 40% income taxes eat $1.33, 2% inflation eats $2.00, and all I do is break even, without any profit. If I consider my overhead expenses, I've made a loss.

@RayButterworth Now consider inflation at 2% but the central bank is lending money at  1% so you can't even get 2% much less 3.33%...

Usury as such was simply lending at interest. It is forbidden in the OT between fellow Israelites but not between Israelites and Gentiles. The Law does not distinguish between exorbitant and reasonable interest. Nor does it distinguish between reasonable insistence that a loan be repaid and unreasonable threats to enforce payment, which would be extortion, a crime in itself whether usury is involved or not.
The word Paul uses in 1 Cor. 6:10 is ἅρπαγες, which is translated "extortioner" and "swindler" or "robber" but not "usurer." So the answer is no, in Paul's list, usury is not a form of as extortion, unless the loan in question was made under false pretenses or it was collected by illegal/sinful threats.

Let's not forget "loan forgiveness scheme" that God commanded in the OT as well as various provisions for to protect those who are bankrupt.

I do not feel I can answer the question fully but can bring out some principles in scripture to show the question has many different contexts to consider.
In general I understand extortion simply from its English meaning: “obtain (something) by force, threats, or other unfair means”. By usury I understand interest on a loan.
From the Mosaic Law there was a ban on making interest on a loan from a brother but not from a foreigner. There are also many specific references to ‘the poor’ possibly separating the topic between mere speculation and trade among the wealthy and a loan to someone in need. This makes four categories to consider,
1. Loan to a poor brother
2. Speculation between rich brothers
3. Loan to a poor foreigner
4. Speculating and trade with a foreigner or even an enemy
As the command to love our neighbor as ourselves, as well as a special duty to our own blood, family, or fellow spiritual brother.
From a standpoint of fairness (something that is not extortion) my own conscience could not accept a loan from someone with abundance to someone in genuine need to be justified as the very act of charging interest on someone truly in need is obscene from the standpoint of love. Where such obscene behavior would become extortion is if the person in need cannot reasonably come out better from the loan and either their situation is so desperate or the interest is high enough that the loan itself could be considered violent against the poor.  This evil interest would especially be obscene among families or worse among believers.
However among those with more than food and clothing and basic essentials of life, who do not genuinely have a material need, it would be their own free choice to enter into a speculative commercial arrangement and I leave such matters to those free parties involved in their business without judgment.
Jesus said we must lend to a brother in need not even expecting the loan to be paid and our loan must be not under compulsion but also a free will gift. This standard even rises higher than that in the Mosaic legislation.  I think the same principles apply and one can’t consider those who are not in need but are both rich and performing speculative trading as unrelated to the duty of love to our poor brother as well as natural family members.
As mentioned in the in the introduction love cannot be so defined by rules to make all questions answered but it can open up principles that the Spirit can use to illuminate to our conscience in order for us to better live in accordance with the law of liberty through the gospel more and more without compulsion. If we were forced to give to others under a church authority against our will with threats of God’s judgment, that could also be a kind of extortion.
